# How to visit websites using iPhone with IPv6 IP address?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, app-store, ipv6

I create a nat64 network using Mac-mini and share it to my iPhone and then it gets an IPv6 address. However, I still cannot visit all websites like apple.com, google.com. 
   Anyone know why it happens, I am looking forward to your kindly answer, Thank you very much!

Comment: I do not know why, but maybe some more info on what exactly appears when you "cannot visit" a website might help as well as maybe some logs on the mac mini in the console. If you share "it" to your mobile there might be some info. Last but not least: The steps how you actually set things up on the "Mac-mini" and correspondingly if you did changes to your mobile might also help those knowing solutions and willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with my iMac 2010. After playing with the configurations for hours I started looking into the developers support.

In my case, I enabled internet sharing from my iMac with NAT64. At first trying with WPA2 wouldnt allow the device to connect to the wifi hosted by my iMac. When I changed it to none with no password, it connected but with no internet access.

I did some digging and found that this is what happened to most Mac Mini running 10.11.4 or 10.11.5. [Here is a discussion from the apple developers support forum.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46933)

As for your case, there are some solutions you could try that have helped others

1. Apple claims that sometimes internet sharing breaks by changing the internet sharing options while the wifi is still on. Solution for that is to go to Network Preferences and remove (using the minus sign) the network connections for wifi and Ethernet (remember to take note of Ethernet settings). Also make sure that under advanced options of wifi, remove any existing saved Wifi networks, it may interfere. Apply the changes, restart the machine and follow the nat64 internet sharing that you originally followed.
2. Turning off the firewall, or unchecking block all incoming connections Renaming the existing internet sharing WiFi name.
3. [Reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295)

I have yet to find a solution to the issue using my iMac, so now I waiting on IT to set me up an IPV6 network.