# Local IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 configuration for ipv6 compatibility testing always offline. iOS app rejected

Tags: ios, app-store, ipv6

Our latest app update was rejected by apple with reason: ***We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network. Specifically, the app does not connect to the internet.***

I have set up a local IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 network [as recommended by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16).

So I have following setup:

**[wifi router]**<--cable-->**[MacBook Pro(Mid 2010) / OS X El Capitan 10.11.6]**<--local IPv6 DNS64/NAT64(shared via wifi)-->**[iphone / iOS 10.0.2]**

Cable connection between router and macbook works fine. The problem is with second part of connection when I am connected via this local IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 test network. Create NAT64 Network checkbox is selected in shared connection config, iphone is connected to the test network and IPv6 ips are assigned when I  check connection details, but internet connection on the iphone doesn't work at all. So I am not able to test my app.

Seems like I am not the only one with this issue, I tried all recommended solutions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253539/4009234), but no luck.

Any advice or recommendations?

Comment: My IPv6 test network setup: [shared network config](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ARxRT.png)

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but i think that ip config should be ok as well: [iphone ip config 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eyG6i.png), [iphone ip config 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SuTVL.png)

Comment: Are you saying that _your app_ doesn't connect to the Internet, or _nothing on the phone_ connects to the Internet? You should be able to e.g. reach web sites in Safari on the phone while connected this way.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah, that's exactly the problem i am not able to connect to the internet with any app or safari when I am connected via that test ipv6 network.